# Convert integer to string in sqldf in R

Tags: r, sqldf

how to converted integer to string in sqldf in R?

```
a=sqldf("SELECT base1.a, base1.b, base2.a 
         FROM base1 
         LEFT JOIN base2 ON base1.a=base2.a")
```

The column `base2.a` is integer but when i do left join i need convert in string, because sometimes start with 0 number .
Exist any function to convert it?

Comment: Hi! Welcome to stack overflow! You meant that `base1.a` is string and something starts with 0, right? Then why not convert `base1.a` to an integer ahead of time?

Answer (score 1):

Use [cast](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#castexpr) or concatenate with an empty string.  Below we show both as well as conversions in the opposite direction.

```
s <- sqldf("select cast(3 as text), 3 || '', cast('012' as int), '012' + 0")
str(s)
```

giving:

```
'data.frame':   1 obs. of  4 variables:
 $ cast(3 as text)   : chr "3"
 $ 3 || ''           : chr "3"
 $ cast('012' as int): int 12
 $ '012' + 0         : int 12
```